# Why I canot import _crop_and_resize in python?

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, importerror

I have header and C++ files, and I built them in Linux to the "_crop_and_resize.so" file (c++ code is [here](https://github.com/liuhantang/DeepFacade/blob/master/roialign/roi_align/build.py)). But I am receiving importError:file too short.

> crop_and_resize.c

> crop_and_resize.h

```
    sources = ['src/crop_and_resize.c']
    headers = ['src/crop_and_resize.h']
    
    extra_compile_args = ['-fopenmp', '-std=c99']
    sources = [os.path.join(this_file, fname) for fname in sources]
    headers = [os.path.join(this_file, fname) for fname in headers]
    extra_objects = [os.path.join(this_file, fname) for fname in extra_objects]
    
    ffi = create_extension(
        '_ext.crop_and_resize',
        headers=headers,
        sources=sources,
        define_macros=defines,
        relative_to=__file__,
        with_cuda=with_cuda,
        extra_objects=extra_objects,
        extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args)
```

After compilation, I am trying to import "***_crop_and_resize.so***" in python, but I am receiving an error.

```
>>> import _crop_and_resize as _backend
```

the error:

```
ImportError:_crop_and_resize.so: file too short
```

specifications:

g++ (GCC)= 9.3.0

python= 3.6.10

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64bit

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: For c extension modules to be used within python, several flags must be enabled when the object is built. Please amend you question to give details for your compilation processes. If `_crop_and_resize.so` was created with a standard setup.py setup, it is very likely that it is only compatible with identical versions of the cpython interpreter

Comment: @AMIRABBAS what is the output of `ldd _crop_and_resize.so`?

Comment: @AMIRABBAS: Stack Overflow is not a service for going to your GitHub repository and diagnosing problems for you. You should narrow your problem down to a specific part of the code and reproduce it with a short program that you post entirely in the question, not as a link to elsewhere.

Comment: @Carson here is the output: 

ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./_crop_and_resize.so'
 not a dynamic executable

Comment: what's the output of `stat _crop_and_resize.so`

Comment: @EugeneSh. from ._ext import crop_and_resize as _backend

Comment: @Carson   File: _crop_and_resize.so
  Size: 0          Blocks: 40         IO Block:     regular empty file
Device:         Inode:             Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (000000/ my username)   Gid: (000000/ my username)
Access: 2022-05-11 10:12:48.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2022-05-11 10:51:27.000000000 -0700
Change: 2022-05-11 10:51:27.000000000 -0700

Comment: @AMIRABBAS that is your problem. The file is empty. It did not download for some reason. Redownload it directly from github.

Comment: @Carson thank you, I just downloaded " _crop_and_resize.so", and now I am receiving this new error! ImportError: /home/amirabb/DeepFacade01/roialign/roi_align/_ext/crop_and_resize/_crop_and_resize.so: undefined symbol: state –

Comment: Please don't spread important info over the comments, [edit] your question instead. Also, you should have created a [mcve] before even asking here, in many cases people find the error themselves, which is why it's required. Also, don't use images of text, so it can be searched. Also, search error messages yourself. Maybe also re-take the [tour] and re-read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for informing me! I will consider it for my next questions!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt could you please let me know why I cannot ask further questions? I already banned by website! this is how treats a client!? if I have a problem, It causes me to ask another website not here?

Comment: It might be because this question was closed due to low quality. You can improve the question though, so that it can be reopened.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I modified it multiple times, ciould you please let me know why I cannot ask new questions?

Comment: @Carson I cannot ask more questions on Stackoverflow, I think I was banned by website, could you please let me know how to raise this issue? I did multiple edits on this question, and I cannot ask new questions yet. Could you please help me to raise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @AMIRABBAS's comment, the output of `stat _crop_and_resize.so` on the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, 64 bit terminal is:

```
File: _crop_and_resize.so
Size: 0 Blocks: 40 IO Block: regular empty file
Device: Inode: Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----) Uid: (000000/ my username) Gid:   
(000000/ my username)
Access: 2022-05-11 10:12:48.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2022-05-11 10:51:27.000000000 -0700
Change: 2022-05-11 10:51:27.000000000 -0700
```

For whatever reason, when downloading the repository, it did not clone the file directly. Needless to say, you cannot link to a zero-length file.

For reference, having downloaded the same file directly from GitHub, the output should be:

```
~/downloads> stat _crop_and_resize.so
File: _crop_and_resize.so
Size: 101304        Blocks: 200        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 19h/25d   Inode: 5602044     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (1000/me)   Gid: (1000/me)
Access: 2022-05-11 14:24:56.233800387 -0400
Modify: 2022-05-11 14:22:48.968012681 -0400
Change: 2022-05-11 14:24:53.433609539 -0400
Birth: 2022-05-11 14:22:48.940010253 -0400
```

Update:_crop_and_resize.so was empty, and I successfully downloaded the file, "_crop_and_resize.so" from its repository, and run it again and the current error gone.